# What's the use of Knowledge in Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: frameworks, synchronization

I am able to implement my own sync framework for client-server synchronization by only using LastUpdateTime as the achor. I don't have to write anything like SyncKnowledge.

seems like Knowledge is helpful in p2p scenario.

what exactly am i missing??

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking

Comment: i cannot use MS sync framework 4.0 because it is CTP. So i decided to write my own framework, which seems to work fine. I have used anchor based algorithm where i store the LastSyncTime on the client side. During sync the client sends asks the server to send all changes after LastSyncTime.               But if you look into MS framework, it also has the concept of Knowledge. My question is do i need to implement this concept in my framework as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're talking about database providers in Sync Framework, there are two types of providers: offline provider and peer-to-peer/collaboration provider.

the former uses anchors to store what has been sent and what has been received and is normally used in hub-spoke type of syncs. in this scenario, only the client keeps track of what has been synched.

the other type of provider uses "knowledge" to store what has been synched and from which replica. thus it can sync peer-to-peer since its tracking as well where the change came from. in this scenario, all replicas store the knowledge.

Sync Framework 4 CTP (which has been postponed) is targeted towards Silverlight, WP7 and other non-MS platform but is actually running on top of Sync Framework 2.1.

Comment: so my understanding is correct. i don't need to care about knowledge